# Linear projection matrix by solving the procrustes problem

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, procrustes

I have two matrices:

```
target = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
               [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
               [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])

source = np.array([[11, 11, 11, 11, 11],
               [22, 22, 22, 22, 22],
               [33, 33, 33, 33, 33]])
```

and I want to create a transformation matrix to project the **source** matrix to the **target** one.

I found that Scipy library provides a function to do it:

```
from scipy.spatial import procrustes
mtx1, mtx2, disparity = procrustes(target, source)
```

based on the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.procrustes.html#scipy.spatial.procrustes), it says that:

[image]

Thus, `mtx2` is the projected matrix.

What if I have another data and I want to project them to the **target** matrix using the "learned transformation matrix" that Scipy used to project the **source** matrix to the **target** one?

How can I do it using Scipy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to modify the function in order to return the transformation matrix (`R`).**

The source code **after removing the comments** looks like:

```
def procrustes(data1, data2):
    mtx1 = np.array(data1, dtype=np.double, copy=True)
    mtx2 = np.array(data2, dtype=np.double, copy=True)

    if mtx1.ndim != 2 or mtx2.ndim != 2:
        raise ValueError("Input matrices must be two-dimensional")
    if mtx1.shape != mtx2.shape:
        raise ValueError("Input matrices must be of same shape")
    if mtx1.size == 0:
        raise ValueError("Input matrices must be >0 rows and >0 cols")

    # translate all the data to the origin
    mtx1 -= np.mean(mtx1, 0)
    mtx2 -= np.mean(mtx2, 0)

    norm1 = np.linalg.norm(mtx1)
    norm2 = np.linalg.norm(mtx2)

    if norm1 == 0 or norm2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("Input matrices must contain >1 unique points")

    # change scaling of data (in rows) such that trace(mtx*mtx') = 1
    mtx1 /= norm1
    mtx2 /= norm2

    # transform mtx2 to minimize disparity
    R, s = orthogonal_procrustes(mtx1, mtx2)
    mtx2 = np.dot(mtx2, R.T) * s    # HERE, the projected mtx2 is estimated.

    # measure the dissimilarity between the two datasets
    disparity = np.sum(np.square(mtx1 - mtx2))

    return mtx1, mtx2, disparity, R
```

Source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/spatial/_procrustes.py#L17-L132

Comment: Thanx @serafeim , this is what I was looking for. One last question, How can I get back the mtx2 matrix to the source shape?

Comment: `mtx2_proj = np.dot(mtx2, R.T)` so `mtx2 = np.dot(mtx2_proj, R)`

Comment: without adding /s? I asked you because I noticed when I do it like you did I get "similar" to the original but standardize around zero (because of the first step in the code, normalization).

Comment: sorry yes. you need to rename the `mtx2` in the code because it gets overwritten when the normalization is applied.