# Get the Transformation Matrix From the SciPy Procrustes Implementation

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, procrustes

The [Procrustes library](https://procrustes.qcdevs.org/index.html) has an example where it demonstrates how to get the Transformation Matrix of two matrices by solving the Procrustes problem. The library seems to be old and doesn't work in Python 3.

I was wondering if there's any way to use the [SciPy implementation of the Procrustes problem](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.procrustes.html) and be able to solve the exact problem discussed in the [library's example](https://procrustes.qcdevs.org/notebooks/Quick_Start.html).

[Another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789245/linear-projection-matrix-by-solving-the-procrustes-problem) seems to need the exact thing that I'm asking here but I can't get it to give me the proper Transformation Matrix [image: Q] that would transform the Source Matrix [image: A] to nearly [image: B]
Using [image: AQ]

In summary, I'd like to be able to implement [this example](https://procrustes.qcdevs.org/notebooks/Quick_Start.html) using the SciPy library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes.html).  Here's a demonstration.  Note that the function `generateAB` only exists to generate the arrays A and B for the demo.  The key steps of the calculation are to center A and B, and then call `orthogonal_procrustes`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ortho_group
from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes


def generateAB(shape, noise=0, rng=None):
    # Generate  A and B for the example.
    if rng is None:
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
    m, n = shape

    # Random matrix A
    A = 3 + 2*rng.random(shape)
    Am = A.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)

    # Random orthogonal matrix T
    T = ortho_group.rvs(n, random_state=rng)

    # Target matrix B
    B = ((A - Am) @ T + rng.normal(scale=noise, size=A.shape)
         + 3*rng.random((1, n)))

    # Include T in the return, but in a real problem, T would not be known.
    return A, B, T


# For reproducibility, use a seeded RNG.
rng = np.random.default_rng(0x1ce1cebab1e)

A, B, T = generateAB((7, 5), noise=0.01, rng=rng)

# Find Q.  Note that `orthogonal_procrustes` does not include
# dilation or translation.  To handle translation, we center
# A and B by subtracting the means of the points.
A0 = A - A.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
B0 = B - B.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)

Q, scale = orthogonal_procrustes(A0, B0)

with np.printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True):
    print('T (used to generate B from A):')
    print(T)
    print('Q (computed by orthogonal_procrustes):')
    print(Q)
    print('\nCompare A0 @ Q with B0.')
    print('A0 @ Q:')
    print(A0 @ Q)
    print('B0 (should be close to A0 @ Q if the noise parameter was small):')
    print(B0)
```

Output:

```
T (used to generate B from A):
[[-0.873  0.017  0.202 -0.44  -0.054]
 [-0.129  0.606 -0.763 -0.047 -0.18 ]
 [ 0.055 -0.708 -0.567 -0.408  0.088]
 [ 0.024  0.24  -0.028 -0.168  0.955]
 [ 0.466  0.272  0.235 -0.78  -0.21 ]]
Q (computed by orthogonal_procrustes):
[[-0.871  0.022  0.203 -0.443 -0.052]
 [-0.129  0.604 -0.765 -0.046 -0.178]
 [ 0.053 -0.709 -0.565 -0.409  0.087]
 [ 0.027  0.239 -0.029 -0.166  0.956]
 [ 0.47   0.273  0.233 -0.779 -0.21 ]]

Compare A0 @ Q with B0.
A0 @ Q:
[[-0.622  0.224  0.946  1.038  0.578]
 [ 0.263  0.143 -0.031 -0.949  0.492]
 [-0.49   0.758  0.473 -0.221 -0.755]
 [ 0.205 -0.74   0.065 -0.192 -0.551]
 [-0.295 -0.434 -1.103  0.444  0.547]
 [ 0.585 -0.378 -0.645 -0.233  0.651]
 [ 0.354  0.427  0.296  0.113 -0.963]]
B0 (should be close to A0 @ Q if the noise parameter was small):
[[-0.627  0.226  0.949  1.032  0.576]
 [ 0.268  0.135 -0.028 -0.95   0.492]
 [-0.493  0.765  0.475 -0.201 -0.75 ]
 [ 0.214 -0.743  0.071 -0.196 -0.55 ]
 [-0.304 -0.433 -1.115  0.451  0.551]
 [ 0.589 -0.375 -0.645 -0.235  0.651]
 [ 0.354  0.426  0.292  0.1   -0.969]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Does the matrix `T` have to be orthogonal for us to be able to approximate it or any matrix `T` can be approximated using this approach?

Also, when you wanted to count for translation you centered the `A` and `B` matrices. How about dilation? is there anything to do to be able to count for that too?